# What happens with Chainlink price feed when L2 sequencer is down?

Tags: chainlink, oracles, rollups, arbitrum

What exactly happens with chainlink price feeds when an L2 sequencer is down? I know that during this moment transactions can be submitted only through L1 rollup contract and that some users can be treated unfairly, but I don't understand what happens with the price feeds on L2.

I've heard bunch of opinions:

1. price is unexpected value
2. price is outdated value but updatedAt not
3. price and updatedAt values are outdated but timestamp of consumer contracts is outdated as well, so they perceive it as new.

Which one is it?